# How to display data that is obtained from an api to a card of angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

The method calls two Apis, the first one obtains information from the user such as his name, id and the id of the applications where the user is registered. The second api obtains information from each application by its id. Then it happens twice to have the information of the two applications but when I want to show each one on an angular material card it only shows me one of the two and not both. I don't know where the error would be.

Called to the apis

```
public userinformacion(datos){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.BASE_URL+"Home/UserApi",datos).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
  public aplicacioninformacion(datos){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.BASE_URL+"Home/ApplicationApi",datos).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Called in the multipleapp.component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    const user = new User();
    user.email = userInfo.email;
    user.roles = userInfo.roles;
    this.userService.userinformacion(user).subscribe((userdata:any)=>{
      for(let i in userdata.user.registrations){
        const Application = new ApplicationViewModel();
        Application.id = userdata.user.registrations[i].applicationId;
        
    this.userService.aplicacioninformacion(Application).subscribe((Applicationdata:any)=>{
             this.datr =(Object.values(Applicationdata));
          console.log(this.datr);
          console.log(Applicationdata);
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Called in the multipleapp.component.html

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div fxFlex.gt-sm="100%">
       <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="400px">
      <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let tile of datr"
                      [colspan]="1"
                      [rowspan]="2">
        <mat-card  style="max-width: 400px;">
          <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>{{tile.name}}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
          </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
               <img mat-card-image src="{{tile.data.imagen}}" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
            </mat-card-content>        
        </mat-card>
         </mat-grid-tile> 
        </mat-grid-list> 
    </div>
</div>
```

In the console if the two data are shown but in the dashboard it does not

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDvdv.jpg)

Only one card is shown and there are two cards that must be shown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DoWs.jpg)

Comment: please add the image descripttion

Answer (score 1):

I have just gone through your code and found you are not persisting the old data of the **this.datr** you are just overwriting the data when new data come from the subscription.

```
 this.datr =(Object.values(Applicationdata));
```

In place of this you can try this:

```
let newData = [...this.datr, Object.values(Applicationdata)]
this.datr = newData;
```

Comment: It helped me a lot, thank you.